# Is it possible to have a 'fake top' iframe in a Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, iframe, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an app that will often be opening external URLs if users click on them within the app. I'm aware that I can use the [InAppBrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) to show external webpages within my app, but the webpage will then take up the whole screen. I'd prefer to have my own UI around the webpage.

If I were using *atom-shell* or *node-webkit* I'd do this using a `webview` or `iframe nwfaketop`, is there anything similar available for Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to disallow it, you could just use normal HTML iframe to show the page. This way, you can do it exactly as you wish.

If there though is restrictions like this, you are stuck with using *InAppBrowser*. But as you know, it will create completely new *WebView* to show the third-party website and thus it will take the whole screen. There is still a way to achieve this by using the [methods](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md) available for the plugin such as [*executeScript*](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md#executescript), [*addEventListener*](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md#addeventlistener) and [close](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md#close). This way, you can inject some HTML (*executeScript*) with button on the top of the page (for example top bar with back button) and when that button is clicked (*addEventListener*), close the window (*close*).